# ctorParameters.map is not a function error

Tags: node.js, angular, angular2-cli

I just install angular2cli from bitbucket. After npm install, ng build and ng serve, and go to localhost:4200 I get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: ctorParameters.map is not a function
    at ReflectionCapabilities.parameters (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:44436:45)
    at Reflector.parameters (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:44570:44)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getDependenciesMetadata (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:25124:54)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getTypeMetadata (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:25089:26)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getDirectiveMetadata (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:24864:28)
    at http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:24933:49
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:24926:44)
    at http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:24914:50
    at Array.forEach (native)
```

Anyone can tell me what problem? i updated the new one but still have this issue and I downgrade to angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.14 seems not working at all. Google it and read a lot of "solution" does not work.

Comment: This is a new issue, probably one of dependencies requires newer `angular-cli` version. Try updating to `angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.25`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error today, here's what i did:

- Downgrade my node version (to node:4.3.2)
- Run npm install -g npm. (To get the latest npm version)
- Update my Angular versions as follow:

> ```
> "@angular/common": "2.4.1",
> "@angular/compiler": "2.4.1",
> "@angular/core": "2.4.1",
> "@angular/forms": "2.4.1",
> "@angular/http": "2.4.1",
> "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.1",
> "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.1",
> "@angular/platform-server": "2.4.1",
> "@angular/router": "3.4.1",
> "rxjs": "5.0.1",
> "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
> ```

- A lot of people have the same issue, maybe [here](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular2-google-maps/issues/812) you can find more info 'bout this issue. Hope it helps.